# How I transfer file details to Vector?

Tags: java, eclipse, vector, split, readfile

I splited the file to String lines and put them in array indexes.

```
String fileString = readfromfile(fileEvents);

String[] fileLines = fileString.split("\n");
```

assuming this is the first index in fileLines:
14  57  9   2   www.buytickets.com

this is the constructor:

```
Orders (int EventID, int SoldtoCustomerID, int SoldtoEmployeesID, int NumberOfTickets, String URL)
```

the vector instance:

```
Vector<Orders> myOrders = new Vector<Orders>();
```

how do I transfer this line to first index in the vecotr so it would be like this:
(14,57,9,2,www.buytickets.com)

thank you :)

Comment: Please don't use the `Vector` class unless you really need the synchronization (which should be rare). Use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I have to. It's for assingnment in university

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that there won't be any invalid entries the following should do the job:

```
    Vector<Orders> myOrders = new Vector<Orders>();

    for (String line : fileLines) {

        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+")

        Orders o = new Orders(
            Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]),
            Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]),
            Integer.valueOf(tokens[2]),
            Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]),
            tokens[4])

        myOrders.add(o)
    }
```

Comment: this example works for case I have only one instance.
what if I want to transfer 10 lines to instances and put them in Vector indexes ?